Starting with Open Data Cube
I am new to Open Data Cube (ODC), and I wish to know the steps I need to follow when working with our data (I am working on Sentinel-1 from ASF). This would be very helpful for me to stay on the correct path.
Could you mention the steps I should take before starting with ODC?
I have followed the ODC installation setup and created some YAML documents related to ODC. I filled them out with metadata information from the dataset loaded into ODC. However, when I try to access this data, I am unable to print the CRS, latitude, longitude, xarray format information, and images. I am confused about whether I am on the right path or if there is something else I need to do to properly load and access our dataset in ODC.

To add a new dataset to a working datacube, you should generally follow the following workflow:

Create a product definition in a YAML file. For example: https://explorer.digitalearth.africa/products/s1_rtc
Add the new product to the datacube using the following command: datacube product add {path to YAML file}
Preprocess the original scene into a working format, such as: unzip data, improve compression, change CRS if needed, organize the files into the desired folders, etc.
Create a YAML file with the EO3 format for the metadata of each image. For example:  https://explorer.digitalearth.africa/products/s1_rtc/datasets/e230e3bd-7f5b-56d0-be55-0fcadf0f17ea
Add each image to the datacube using the following command: datacube dataset add {path to YAML file}
Verify in PgAdmin that files are correctly indexed and load data using Python. For loading data, you can use: https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/indexed-data/generate/datacube.Datacube.load.html
Use the data to create meaningful products. Remember that datacube makes use of Xarray, and Xarray uses Dask and NumPy, so I recommend you read the documentation of all three.

Some good starting points are:

https://docs.digitalearthafrica.org/en/latest/sandbox/notebooks/Beginners_guide/index.html
https://docs.digitalearthafrica.org/en/latest/sandbox/notebooks/Frequently_used_code/index.html
https://knowledge.dea.ga.gov.au/notebooks/How_to_guides/Generating_geomedian_composites/

DEAfrica and DEAustralia have their own set of toolboxes, so I recommend reading them properly and identifying which of them you can use, as they are built for their particular datasets.
Remember to adapt the YAML files to your own data, as they cannot be used directly, unfortunately.
S1-RTC images are a great start for using Radar data. Just be careful with making composites. I recommend using LRW (David Small) for mosaics: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9352976
